# I have problem wrapping divs with minmax css grid

Tags: css, grid, css-grid, minmax

Why do these 2 divs wrap on 300px? Shouldn't they wrap when the element hits the min value in minmax?
I tried both auto-fit and auto-fill but it still doesn't work.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(150px, 300px));
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your question you talk about 3 divs while there are only 2. Also what do you expact to happen?

Comment: My bad, but it should work the same with 2. I expect that they will wrap when they reach 150px width.

Comment: Is that something they should always do or is there a change that they can be 300px width as well?

Comment: From what i understood, they should be each 300px width as long as they have enough space. When you get on a smalled device, they should either shrink to fit, or wrap if they cant be at least 150px wide.